# How do you reorder the categorical values in a bar graph? [R]

Tags: r, graph

Specifically, it is possible to reproduce the problem in 2 steps.

(1) load [this txt file](http://www.liaad.up.pt/~ltorgo/DataMiningWithR/DataSets/Analysis.txt) into R [with](http://www.liaad.up.pt/~ltorgo/DataMiningWithR/code2.html)

```
algae <- read.table('http://www.liaad.up.pt/~ltorgo/DataMiningWithR/DataSets/Analysis.txt',
         header=F,
         dec='.',
         col.names=c('season','size','speed','mxPH','mnO2','Cl','NO3','NH4','oPO4','PO4','Chla','a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7'),
         na.strings=c('XXXXXXX'))
```

(2) plot with `plot(algae$speed)`.

The categorical values will be ordered as "high", "low", "medium". However, I'd like them to be "high", "medium", "low". Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
algae$speed <- factor(algae$speed, levels=c("low", "medium", "high"))
plot(algae$speed)
```